# How do I get a disclosure indicator in my tableview header section?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, header, tableview

I'm customizing my headers in my Tableview and I want to add a discloure indicator (arrow) to my header that is clickable, is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already customized your header view you can simply add a custom UIButton with an image of a  discloure indicator add add it as a subview to your header view.

If you need further help you are most welcome.

**EDIT**
Jonathan is right, the UIButton has a **UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure** so there is no need for a custom image.

Comment: I found out that UIButton comes with a preset Detail Disclosure button type, so instead of using my own image, I can just do this:   `UIButton *btn = [UIButton ButtonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];`

Comment: The UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure is the blue circle not the DisclosureIndicator. It does not appear the button has this as a standard image.

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the header view using

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayHeaderView:(UIView *)view forSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Then fetch the actual header view

`UITableViewHeaderFooterView *header = (UITableViewHeaderFooterView *)view;`

Create a button with detail disclosure

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
```

Then set the frame of this button and add it to the header view